# Multidimensional string variables in Julia JuMP

Tags: optimization, syntax, julia, julia-jump

I am defining multidimensional variables in JuMP, however, I require the indices to be strings for ease of operation. Some of the indices might not be distinct. How do I set up multidimensional variables in JuMP while allowing for repeat elements?

I have already tried defining the variables as variables of strings. However, once the number of indices or dimension of the variable exceeds 3, then error is stating that the index should be of type ::Int64.

```
Set1 = Set{String}(["One", "Two", "Three"])
Set2 = Set{String}(["This", "That", "Where", "There"])
Set3 = Set{String}([1,2,3,4,5])
Set4 = Set{String}(["Where", "There"])

@variable(model, x[Set1, Set2, Set2, Set3, Set4] >= 0)
```

This gives the error that the index is of not of type ::Int64, since the indices exceed dimension 3.

This works fine:

```
@variable(model, y[Set1, Set2] >= 0)
```

In order to limit the dimension I have tried to make the variable two dimensional as below:

```
@variable(model, x[Set1, [Set2, Set2, Set3, Set4]] >= 0)
```

However, this gave the error that the index is repeated (Set2).

Is there a proper workaround or syntactical correction?

Answer (score 0):

After evaluating the sets and arrays in the solution, I found that the errors were not given if the indices are described other than "Sets".

Therefore, in order to have multidimensional variables with string indices, declare the indices as Arrays and not Sets.

Answer (score 0):

When I have implemented non-integer indicies, I have usually done it using symbols instead of strings. The conversion between the two is quite easy and the idea of a symbol seems more like what sets are, but I did that using arrays instead of sets so I am not certainly if it will fix the problem.

I would encourage you to look into [AxisArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/AxisArrays.jl) as an alternative data structure as well. JuMP stores its variables in AxisArrays so it plays quite nicely with the rest of the code base.